# Translate x axis points into years

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need some help with rendering Highcharts. I am trying to create a highchart so that the data that I get from my Rails Server will render this chart.

[image]

So far, I've only gotten my chart to look like the one below:

[image]

There are obviously many things wrong with my chart compared to the one that I am trying to create. The visual aspect of the chart doesn't concern me. What concerns me is the xAxis of the chart. I absolutely just cannot seem to get my highcharts to have yearly values. No matter what I do, the time gets rendered in milliseconds and this is F$@#ING infuriating.

Below is my <kbd>chart.js.erb</kbd> file:

```
var presentDay = new Date();
var year = presentDay.getFullYear();
var year = year - 3;
var month = presentDay.getMonth();
var day = presentDay.getDay();

$(function() {
  new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: "graphModal",
      height: 450,
      width: 700,
      borderWidth: 5,
      borderColor: '#525252'
    },
    title: {
      text: "Project Comparison Graph"
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: '# of contributors who made changes to the project source code each month'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        year: '%Y'
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Contributors'
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        pointStart: Date.UTC(year, month, day),
        pointIntervalUnit: 'month',
        lineColor: 'red'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 30, 45, 78, 43, 32, 20,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 30, 45, 78, 43, 32, 20,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 30, 45, 78, 43, 32, 20]
    }]
  });
});
```

The JavaScript code at the very top of the file creates a date from 3 years ago from which I start my chart on `pointStart`. I have 36 plot points. One for each month of the year. If I wanted data from three years ago the code will execute April 10, 2012 up until now. Instead of a nice clean chart I get what you see above. How do I fix this? I got this code from this example on jsFiddle:

```
 $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                month: '20' + '%y'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4,29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4,29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2012, 0, 1),
            pointIntervalUnit: 'month'
        }]
    });
});
```

I got it to work on the fiddle so isn't it working now?

Comment: Can you link to a jsFiddle demo exhibiting the problem?

Comment: You can use `'{value:%Y}'` to format your dates (http://jsfiddle.net/PwEnd/589/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply guys. I think there is something wrong with my backend. I've copied and pasted my code on my rails app into jsfiddle and it renders perfectly.

Comment: Here is how you can git rid of the markers: http://jsfiddle.net/dLz3Lv08/

Comment: And here is a shadow on the line: http://jsfiddle.net/dLz3Lv08/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is really close to the example image, all I added was the following JavaScript (setting a width requires a custom shadow):

```
plotOptions: {
  /*Your original values...*/
  line: {
    marker: {enabled:false},
    shadow: {
        color: '#000',
        width: 5,
        opacity: 0.15,
        offsetY: 2,
        offsetX: 2
    },
    lineWidth: 4
  }
}
```

```js
var presentDay = new Date();
var year = presentDay.getFullYear();
var year = year - 3;
var month = presentDay.getMonth();
var day = presentDay.getDay();

$(function() {
  new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: "container",
      height: 450,
      width: 700,
      borderWidth: 5,
      borderColor: '#525252'
    },
    title: {
      text: "Project Comparison Graph"
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: '# of contributors who made changes to the project source code each month'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        year: '%Y'
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Contributors'
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        pointStart: Date.UTC(year, month, day),
        pointIntervalUnit: 'month',
        lineColor: 'red'
      },
      line: {
        marker: {
          enabled: false
        },
        shadow: {
          color: '#000',
          width: 5,
          opacity: 0.15,
          offsetY: 2,
          offsetX: 2
        },
        lineWidth: 4
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 30, 45, 78, 43, 32, 20, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 30, 45, 78, 43, 32, 20, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 30, 45, 78, 43, 32, 20]
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```